# SQL Server - Construct update where clause based on condition

Tags: sql-server-2008

Please see below query:

```
Update Employee
Set AccountManagerId = a.AM_ID
FROM Employee e INNER JOIN AccountManager a on e.Id = a.Id
WHERE
```

**Struggling to construct below part (which needs to be added to the where clause)**

```
If a.Department is not null then [FOLLOWING NEEDS TO BE ADDED TO WHERE CLAUSE] (e.Department = a.department)
```

Struggling to add this to where clause. So if department is not NULL then add this to WHERE clause

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Update Employee
Set AccountManagerId = a.AM_ID
FROM Employee e INNER JOIN AccountManager a on e.Id = a.Id
WHERE ((a.Department IS NULL) || (e.Department = a.department))
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you not do:

```
Update Employee
Set AccountManagerId = a.AM_ID,
e.Department = a.department
FROM Employee e INNER JOIN AccountManager a on e.Id = a.Id
WHERE
a.Department IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: @mattytommo - exactly! The aim is to get my rep so high it will cause a stackoverflow exception :o)

Comment: @mattytommo - bigint has a limit of 9,223,372,036,854,775,807 - malcolm birtle would have a fit using 8 bytes for a field!

Comment: @mattytommo - where does it say that? Here it states that the maximum value is 2^63, which is 9,223,372,036,854,775,807.  If the value goes higher it would need to allocate more bytes to the field and be a different type: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187745.aspx

Comment: You'd have to call .ToByteArray() on the bigint and save it as something like an `image` in SQL: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/system.numerics.biginteger.tobytearray.aspx

Comment: @mattytommo - lol dooche! Int64 maps directly to BigInt in SQL m8

Answer (score 0):

Why not just add another condition to the join?

I believe this will achieve what you intend, to only update Employees with matching Account Managers who have a Department.

```
UPDATE Employee
SET AccountManagerId = a.AM_ID
FROM Employee e 
INNER JOIN AccountManager a 
ON e.Id = a.Id
AND
e.Department = a.Department
```

Comment: I `think` he is trying to update the Employee department column with the AccountManager department column

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what's going on. If it's clarified I'll update / remove my answer as appropriate